# Expand left div to take remaining width, without swapping elements, with a specified height

Tags: css, html

Before this is marked as a duplicate, please hear me out. I want a column layout consisting of 2 or more columns. The first div (the element to the left), is supposed to expand to take the remaining width, whilst the columns to the right have a specific width. There a tons of these questions of StackOverflow although none describe this case.

I could use a table layout; (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NmrbP/6/)

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

The problem with this approach is that I cannot set the height of the table (the height is ignored for any `table-cell`) and the column layout is supposed to stretch to fit 100% of the parent's height.

I could utilize floating elements combined with `overflow:hidden`; (http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/)

```
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

The problem with this approach is the fact that the elements have been swapped (i.e. the left element is defined after the right). This does not work for responsive websites, where the left element is supposed to appear before the right element (e.g. SmartPhones). AFAIK I cannot swap the elements with pure CSS, which I must do for smaller resolutions.

Any solutions for this?

TL;DR I want the first (left) column to expand, whilst the rest have a specific width. All columns must have a height of 100% (i.e fit to the parent's height), and the elements should not swap places in the markup.

Comment: If you don't need support for old browsers, you can go for flex display

Answer (score 2):

look for [**calc() function in css3**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) ??

your solution here : **http://jsfiddle.net/NmrbP/19/**

wrap everything inside a `master` container and then float them....(*dont forget to clear the float*)

**CSS**

```
  #master {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#divLeft {
    float:left;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: calc(100% - 250px); /* extra loaded stuff by me */
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 250px); /* to make cross browser */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 250px);  /* to make cross browser */
    height:100%; /* give div full height */
}
#divRight {
    float:left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    vertical-align: top;
    width : 250px; /* extra loaded stuff by me */
    height:100%; /* give div full height */
}

.clr{
    clear:both; /* extra loaded stuff by me */
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `calc()` isn't [available in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). Some of us still have to support it, unfortunately

Comment: @Bojangles : WIDR, OP mentioned, `table-cell`, that is also not supported in IE8...so i thought, browser considerations is IE8+!!

Comment: @Bojangles...apologies...sligt typo there `-` was missing..i mean to say IE8- :)

Comment: @Bojangles The question is marked as CSS3, so I think IE8 is not important here ;)

Comment: That would be viable approach, besides the fact that the number of columns to the right are dynamic (i.e I cannot use a static width for the calculation).

Comment: @ElliottDarfink : i worked on this line => `whilst the columns to the right have a specific width`...assuming a specific width, use `calc(100% - specific_width)`!

Comment: Yes, each (right) column has a static width, but the number of columns are not.

Comment: By using pre-defined classes?

Comment: thats obvious....but considering you requirement...how do address the fact that all the div have combined width <= specific width....if you do this then my answer will help you!! :)